# filtering does not work with indexing on seq() data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, seq

i generated a data.table based on a sequence from 1.25 to 2. At the next step i like to filter all values that meet a criteria of one of the sequence points. When indexing to Payouts$sequence[15] the filtering ist not working.

Not working

```
Payouts<-data.table(sequence=as.numeric(seq(from=1.25, to=2, by=0.05)))
RePro<-data.table(PH=1.95,Home="Example")
RePro %>% filter(PH == as.numeric(Payouts$sequence[15]))
```

If i index directly to a number (here 1.95) its working

```
Payouts<-data.table(sequence=as.numeric(seq(from=1.25, to=2, by=0.05)))
RePro<-data.table(PH=1.95,Home="Example")
RePro %>% filter(PH == 1.95)
```

Anyone with a reason for that or a solution?

Comment: Check this out: `print(seq(from=1.25, to=2, by=0.05)[15], digits = 20)`. Then study [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059).

Comment: Perfect Thank you!